Text to SQL using Azure OpenAI
I am attempting to extract an SQL query from a simple text by using Azure OpenAI and Langchain. I am applying a filter condition that should generate an SQL query based on specific table details from a CSV file. The CSV file contains columns for table name, table description, and schema name. The resulting SQL query should include both the schema name and the table name. However, I am currently encountering an issue where the schema name is not being included in the query; instead, the query is being generated without it.
**Code:**
from operator import itemgetter
from langchain.chains.openai_tools import create_extraction_chain_pydantic
from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel, Field
from typing import List
import pandas as pd

def get_table_details():
    



# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
    table_description = pd.read_csv("database_table_descriptions.csv")
    table_docs = []

    # Iterate over the DataFrame rows to create Document objects
    table_details = ""
    for index, row in table_description.iterrows():
        table_details = table_details + "Table Name:" + row['table'] + "\n" + "Table Description:" + row['description'] +  "\n" + "Schema Name:" + row['schema'] +"\n\n"

    return table_details


class Table(BaseModel):
    """Table in SQL database."""

    name: str = Field(description="Name of table in SQL database.")
    schema_name: str = Field(description="schema of table in SQL database.")

table_details = get_table_details()
print(table_details)

table_details_prompt = f"""Return the names of ALL the SQL tables and names of ALL the SQL schema that MIGHT be relevant to the user question. \
The tables are:

{table_details}

Remember to include ALL POTENTIALLY RELEVANT tables, even if you're not sure that they're needed."""`

table_chain = create_extraction_chain_pydantic(Table, llm, system_message=table_details_prompt)
def get_tables(tables: List[Table]) -> List[str]:
    tables  = [f"{table.schema_name}.{table.name}" for table in tables]
    return tables

select_table = {"input": itemgetter("question")} | create_extraction_chain_pydantic(Table, llm, system_message=table_details_prompt) | get_tables
chain = (
RunnablePassthrough.assign(schema_and_table_names_to_use=select_table) |
RunnablePassthrough.assign(query=generate_query).assign(
    result=itemgetter("query") | execute_query
)
)
res = chain.invoke({"question": "what is the ftpjndi for tradingpartner Rockwood for table qtc_asn"})`

**Output:**
{'question': 'what is the ftpjndi for tradingpartner Rockwood for table qtc_asn',
 'schema_and_table_names_to_use': ['mule.qtc_asn'],
 'query': 'SELECT "ftpjndi" FROM qtc_asn WHERE tradingpartner = \'RockwoodSyspro\' LIMIT 1;',
 'result': ''}





**Expected output:**
{'question': 'what is the ftpjndi for tradingpartner Rockwood for table qtc_asn',
 'schema_and_table_names_to_use': ['mule.qtc_asn'],
 'query': 'SELECT "ftpjndi" FROM mule.qtc_asn WHERE tradingpartner = \'RockwoodSyspro\' LIMIT 1;',
 'result': 'abc/xyz'}

